# Problem with Ingress when following documentation steps using the NGINX Ingress Controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, minikube

I have followed the steps of the docs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress) to set up an ingress on minikube, but when It comes to verifying if the IP address is set, executing the command `kubectl get service web` Is not retrieving the same results as the docs. Hence I can't continue with the docs example.

My output:

[image]

The docs output:
[image]

So my question is regarding why I am getting `localhost` instead of the IP number, and also under the `CLASS` column I'm getting `nginx` instead of `<none>` any clue to follow would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localhost for the address looks valid.

You can get your minikube cluster ip with below and proceed.

```
minikube ip
```

Comment: Hi sridhar, thank you very much for the answer! 192.168.49.2 this is the IP I get, I mapped that in the hosts file with hello-world.info and it worked!